# How to draw my stored polygon from database onto the google map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

For angular google maps I want it possible for me to draw my stored polygon array of markers onto the map.

The tech I'm using is: Angular version 1 with JavaScript, using an angular directive and templateUrl.

**This is my html directive template:**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="config.map.center" zoom="config.map.zoom" options="config.map.options" events="config.map.events" draggable="true">

        <ui-gmap-polygon path="compatiblePolygon" stroke="polygonConfig.stroke" fill="polygonConfig.fill" fit="true" static="true" visible="polygonConfig.visible" editable="polygonConfig.editable" draggable="polygonConfig.draggable" clickable="true" events="polygonConfig.events">
        </ui-gmap-polygon>

        <ui-gmap-markers models="compatiblePoints" coords="'self'" idKey="'id'"
            options="pointsConfig.options"
            clickable="true">
        </ui-gmap-markers>

        <ui-gmap-drawing-manager options="config.drawing.options" static="true" control="drawingManagerControl" events="config.drawing.events"></ui-gmap-drawing-manager>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store your polygon as an encoded string in database, instead of polygon coordinates.
you can obtain encoded polygon as follows:

```
/* This function save latitude and longitude to the polygons[] variable after we call it. */
    function encodePolygon(polygon)
    {
        //This variable gets all bounds of polygon.
        var path = polygon.getPath();

        var encodeString = 
        google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);

        /* store encodeString in database */
    }
```

Then you can redraw your polygon from encode string any time using:

```
function DrawPolygon(encodedString){
    var decodedPolygon =   
   google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedString);

            var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: decodedPolygon,
                editable: false,
                strokeColor: '#FFFF',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FFFF',
                fillOpacity: 0.35
            });
}
```

Comment: Problem is that my directive doesn't no the name Google

Comment: - Make sure you load the google API before the directive file in index.html
- Drop the http[s] argument in the path
- You are not behind any proxy.
See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567602/javascript-error-cant-find-variable-google

Comment: I tried all those things and still get the error: "Cannot find name 'google' '"

Comment: Ask this under a separate question, or better yet search for similar issues people faced earlier. 
The given answer provides solution to the question asked here.

Comment: Go another one for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447127/im-using-angular-google-maps-and-need-help-getting-the-new-bounds-changed-from