# I'm using angular google maps and need help getting the new bounds changed from the event fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

This is my current code which is called when bounds are changed and works:

```
 scope.boundsChanged= function(arg){
       console.log(arg);                       
 };
```

I basically need the new array of lat and lng when this function above is called.
I'm unsure are the retrieve it.

I'm using angular version 1 with JavaScript in a directive using a templateUrl.

**Img of console log of bounds arg:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what is returned in the boundsChanged() function, but assuming changed bounds are returned in the function, method is the same to get lat, lng coordinates:

```
scope.boundsChanged= function(arg){

    //assuming changed bounds is returned as the 'arg'
    var polygonBounds = arg;
    var coordinates = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < polygonBounds.length; i++)
    {
        coordinates.push({lat: polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), lng: polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()});
        coordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()));
    }

   console.log(arg);                       
};
```

Comment: I only get 1 set of lat and lng for polygonBounds. Theres no array of latt lngs like I need

Comment: It depends on what are you getting in arg, and what are you getting out. Example code and output would help to understand it exactly.

Comment: added console img above

Comment: Unable to get anything from this information. If you can make a plunker, may be I can help you a bit on debugging.